# How to plot/graph an arbitrary equation

Tags: c#, plot, equation

Assuming that parsing the equation would not be a problem, how can I make an algorithm to plot an arbitrary equation, given a specific canvas size? As in, getting the coordinates of all the pixels to highlight?

I've tried just repeatedly calculating Y given X, but it comes out looking sloppy.

This is not a homework question.

By plot i mean graph really, like how a graphing calculator plots an equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "looking sloppy"?

Comment: Where are your equations coming from? How are you parsing them into something that can be understood by the program?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the graph plotting libraries? no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: What kind of equation? Two variables? Hard question. Three variables? Even harder. Not all the equations can be represented in explicit form. E.G. the circumference equation: ax^2 + by^2 = c^2.

Comment: By looking sloppy, i mean that there are pixels that are out of place, i'm looking for something that would come out more like [this.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Bresenham.svg) And parsing the equation is not the problem here, i can have the script calculate the Y from an equation given X just fine.

Comment: Have you investigated on Bresenhams algorithms? Despite that, having a plotting library isn't that bad of an idea.

Comment: Perhaps computing the Taylor series might help, but note that this only applies if your functions are (infinitely) derivable.

Comment: By arbitrary equation, i mean it could be something crazy like (5^(x/3))/(2x^4), so drawing a straight line is not the solution.

Comment: How? Calculate point coordinates and use `Graphics.DrawCurve()`

Comment: Use Bresenhams algorithms, they will get you out of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the (Windows Forms) DataVisualization Charting library contained in .NET Framework 4. API documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx) and technical reference pages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456726.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing each pixel separately, you could consider using a spline curve. The `System.Drawing.Graphics` for instance has a `DrawCurve` method that draws a smoothed curve (a spline) through a number of points. Additionally set the`SmoothingMode` to `AntiAlias`

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

---

Consider passing the functions as lambda expressions if possible. That's easier than parsing an expression given as string.

```
public void DrawCurve(PointF[] points, Func<float,float> f)
{
    ...
    float y = f(x);
    ...
}
```

E.g.

```
DrawCurve(points, x => (float)Math.Sin(x)/(x * x + 1);
```